# How to get column value with customize array in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a query result like the one below in the `c_order` table for the `c_order_id` column.

| c_order_id |
| --- |
| 1001 |
| 1002 |
| 1003 |
| 1004 |
| 1005 |
| 1006 |
| 1007 |
| 1008 |
| 1009 |
| 1010 |
| .... |
| .... |
| .... |

I need a query for the below result.

| c_order_id |
| --- |
| 1001,1002,1003, 1004,1005,1006, 1007,1008,1009, 1010,....,.... |

or

| c_order_id |
| --- |
| 1001,1002,1003,1004, 1005,1006,1007,1008, 1009,1010,....,.... |

I am concerned with `array_to_string(array_agg(c_order_id), e'\n')` where I get an array result but in per array value in per new line. Here I can't customize the array value with a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Do two levels of aggregation:

```
select string_agg(col_3, '\n')
from (select string_agg(col, ',') as col_3
      from (select t.*,
                    row_number() over (order by col) - 1 as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      group by floor(seqnum / 3)
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gordon Linoff. But need little correction

```
select string_agg(col_3, e'\n') c_order_id
from (select string_agg(c_order_id::character varying, ',') as col_3
      from (select t.c_order_id,
                    row_number() over (order by c_order_id) - 1 as seqnum
            from c_order t
           ) t
      group by floor(seqnum / 4)
     ) c_order ;
```